# Facebook user email extended permissions with new SDK

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, email

I am currently using the code below in my Codeigniter application to get Facebook data from an app user.

```
<?php


 require_once('facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook= new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '2453463636',
      'secret' => '365653656565656',
      'allowSignedRequest' => false,
));

$_REQUEST += $_GET;
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
   // $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=picture.width(100).height(100),first_name,last_name,username,email');
    echo $user_profile['email'];
    echo $user_profile['username'];

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
}

?>
```

This works fine in connecting and returns the `username`  of the user echoed on the page, however the email does not work. The email returns shows up as an error on the view "Undefined index: email".

I used this very same thing to get the email just a few days ago and it worked, however that was on localhost. It get the email fine on localhost, when pushed to the server, it doesn't recognize `email`, but it does recognize and get the `username`.

Why isn't the email being recognized?

I am using the latest version of the sdk: ***Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3)***

Answer (score 1):

You can't do with this options. You need extended permission from Facebook. Check this link for more details:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Facebook Doesn't share user email without their permission.

Comment: +1 for pointing "Facebook Doesn't share user email without their permission"

Comment: @KiranRS But where and how? Can you provide the code statement?